# Integral of a polynomial fraction: $\int \frac{4x^2-3x+2}{4x^2-4x+3}dx$

Tags: calculus

I have initially used long division to obtain: $$1+\frac{x-1}{4x^2-4x+3}$$
Now, I'm having difficulty solving $$\int \frac{x-1}{4x^2-4x+3}dx$$
Even if I do the $u$-substitution i.e. $u=4x^2-4x+3$ hence, $du=8x-4$ and $dx=\frac{1}{8x-4}du$, I can't seem to figure out how to deal with the $x-1$ in the numerator.
Any help regarding this will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: The substitution you can up with lets you evaluate $\int \frac {x-\frac1  2} {4x^{2}-4x+3}dx$. To evaluate $\int \frac 1 {4x^{2}-4x+3}dx$ write $4x^{2}-4x+3$ as $4(x-\frac1 2)^{2}+\frac 1 2$ and make the substiution $z=x-\frac  1 2$. Use the fact that $\int \frac 1 {z^{2}+c^{2}}dz=\frac 1  c \arctan \frac z c$ plus a constant.

Answer (score 4):

**Hints:**

$$2\frac{x-1}{4x^2-4x+3}=\frac{2x-2}{(2x-1)^2+2}=\frac{2x-1}{(2x-1)^2+2}-\frac1{(2x-1)^2+2}.$$

In the first term, the numerator is the derivative of the denominator (to a coefficient). In the second, we recognize the derivative of the arc tangent, modulo simple transformations.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Separate $x-1$ into $(x-1/2) -(1/2)$ and now perform these two integrals. The intuition behind this is that you can use your $u$-sub on the $x-1/2$ part as it is $(8x-4)/8$